# Анимация скрытия и раскрытия горизонтального списка с неизвестной шириной

Tags: html, css, css3, reactjs, css-animation

https://codesandbox.io/s/lxlwrv9y57

React

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './styles.css'

function App(props) {
  const [open, toggle] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <button onClick={() => toggle(!open)} className="button">
        Click
      </button>
      <div className={`list ${open ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}>
        <div className="item">Item 1</div>
        <div className="item">Item 2</div>
        <div className="item">Item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #969696;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  transition: width 1s linear 0.3s;
}

.inactive {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Нужно сделать анимация раскрытия списка слева направо при раскрытии, и справа налево при закрытии. Может есть какие то библиотеки, пробовал react-motion и react-spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Нужно сделать анимация раскрытия списка слева направо при раскрытии, и
>   справа налево при закрытии.

Можно [с помощью анимации](http://codesandbox.io/s/yv3169z8ov) сделать (без всяких библиотек, на чистом CSS).

Comment: ну можно же нормальную анимацию сделать, что это за сжатие